# Spring WS transformingInterceptor XSLT duplicating request

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I am trying to modify SOAP requests that come into our Spring WS webservice. I have the transforming interceptor transforming the document, but instead of modifying the existing values, a duplicate request is made with the modified values.

Here is my XSLT code (limited to xsl version 1.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="text() != '' ">
                    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="text()" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'Yoshi'" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'Cannot do that here'" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="replace"/>
        <xsl:param name="by"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

An example SOAP request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header />
   <soapenv:Body>
      <LinkRequest>
         <PayorFirstName>Jimmy</PayorFirstName>
         <PayorLastName>Test</PayorLastName>
         <Description>Some top secret test</Description>
         <CustomMessage>Eat it, Yoshi</CustomMessage>
      </LinkRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And what the request looks like AFTER the transformation:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header />
   <soapenv:Body>
      <LinkRequest>
         <PayorFirstName>Jimmy</PayorFirstName>
         <PayorLastName>Test</PayorLastName>
         <Description>Some top secret test</Description>
         <CustomMessage>Eat it, Yoshi</CustomMessage>
      </LinkRequest>
      <LinkRequest>
         <PayorFirstName>Jimmy</PayorFirstName>
         <PayorLastName>Test</PayorLastName>
         <Description>Some top secret test</Description>
         <CustomMessage>Eat it, Cannot do that here</CustomMessage>
      </LinkRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would like to search the request for all instances of a word (In this case, "Yoshi") and replace those instances with something else (In this case "Cannot do that here");

Answer (score 1):

When I apply your stylesheet to your input XML, it results in the following XML, so I think your XSLT is correct, but perhaps the code catching it and writing back the results is inserting it again in the body?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <LinkRequest>
      <PayorFirstName>Jimmy</PayorFirstName>
      <PayorLastName>Test</PayorLastName>
      <Description>Some top secret test</Description>
      <CustomMessage>Eat it, Cannot do that here</CustomMessage>
    </LinkRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However, I would like to suggest a slightly different approach for your XSLT stylesheet. Because, as written, it does not take into account nested or mixed (elements and text) content nodes, and it would also search parts that are outside of the SOAP body (I left the `string-replace-all` template out for brevity):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()[parent::*[not(namespace-uri(.) = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')]]">
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'Yoshi'" />
            <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'Cannot do that here'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the same thing, tested offline it worked as desired, but as soon as it was implemented into the webservice, it failed. But I will use your xslt for better implementation, though it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Orin probably a good idea to ask a new Java/spring-only question about that part, explaining and showing what code you used to invoke the stylesheet, that could shed some light on that.